# Filter Subform, Starts With, Multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to filter a subform based on data put into a text box.
The code below will show the record if the `Student ID` is typed perfectly.
I want to have my filter show any records in which the `Student ID`, `First Name` or `Last Name` starts with `Me.Sort.Text`

```
Private Sub Sort_Change()
If IsNull(Me.Sort.Text) Or Me.Sort.Text = "" Then
    Me.Students_subform.Form.FilterOn = False
Else
    Me.Students_subform.Form.FilterOn = True
    Me.Students_subform.Form.Filter = "[Student ID] ='" & Me.Sort.Text & "'"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So if `Me.Sort.Text` contains the text *"foo"*, you want to build a filter expression string such as `"[Student ID] Like 'foo*' OR [First Name] Like 'foo*' OR [Last Name] Like 'foo*'"`  Did I understand correctly?

Comment: I think this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need a filter expression with 3 `Like` conditions `OR`'d together.

For example if `Me.Sort.Text` contains the text *"foo"*, build a filter expression string such as ...

```vb
 "[Student ID] Like 'foo*' OR [First Name] Like 'foo*' OR [Last Name] Like 'foo*'"
```

I tested this code in Access 2010 and it filters the subform as I think you want ...

```vb
Private Sub Sort_Change()
    Dim strFilter As String

    With Me.Sort
        If Len(.Text & vbNullString) > 0 Then
            strFilter = "[Student ID] Like '" & .Text & _
                "*' OR [First Name] Like '" & .Text & _
                "*' OR [Last Name] Like '" & .Text & "*'"
        End If
    End With
    Debug.Print "strFilter: " & strFilter '<- inspect this in Immediate window
                                          ' Ctrl+g will take you there
    With Me.Students_subform.Form
        If Len(strFilter) = 0 Then
            .FilterOn = False
        Else
            .Filter = strFilter
            .FilterOn = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Good, I thought that's what you were after.  One point which bothers me a little is that you will alter the subform `.Filter` with each keystroke in the *Sort* text box.  If that proves to be too much load on the database engine, consider using the text box's After Update (instead of its Change event) to apply the `.Filter`

Comment: Thats a good idea. I will switch to that If I start to have problems.